# Jquery to JS conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an extension and trying to convert all my jquery to vanilla js.
Here is a jquery snippet which I am trying to convert

```js
$('table tr th:eq(2)').hide();
$('table tr').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td:eq(2)').hide();
});
```

This is what I tried but it doesn't work. I am stuck on it.

```js
document.querySelector('table tr th:nth-child(2)').style.display = 'none';
document.querySelectorAll('table tr').forEach(el => {
   el.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').style.display = 'none';
})
```

Update: changed `->` to `=>` as told however this is not the only problem

Comment: Yes, as I said in the comments, kindly change `*:nth-child(2)` instead of `td:nth-child(2)` might be more successful. See [**demo**](https://jsbin.com/ziyikaqico/edit?html,output).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a syntax error in JavaScript: `(el -> {` It is supposed to be `(el => {`. Change it to:

```
document.querySelector('table tr th:nth-child(2)').style.display = 'none';
document.querySelectorAll('table tr').forEach(el => {
   el.querySelector('*:nth-child(2)').style.display = 'none';
});
```

Also it's better to now use arrow functions in this case, just for more compatibility.

**Snippet**

Using [`NodeList.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) demo:

```js
document.querySelector('table tr th:nth-child(2)').style.display = 'none';
document.querySelectorAll('table tr').forEach(el => {
   el.querySelector('*:nth-child(2)').style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Included update from comment, using `for ... of` demo:

```js
document.querySelector('table tr th:nth-child(2)').style.display = 'none';
for (el of document.querySelectorAll('table tr')) {
  el.querySelector('*:nth-child(2)').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I made the change as you mentioned thank you for that. for me `document.querySelector('table tr th:nth-child(2)').style.display = 'none'; `  is not working

Comment: @LoveshDongre Can you also give a sample HTML, because it worked for me.

Comment: @LoveshDongre Try using `*:nth-child(2)` instead of `td:nth-child(2)` might be more successful. See [**demo**](https://jsbin.com/ziyikaqico/edit?html,output).

Comment: @StackSlave - say hello to NodeList.prototype.forEach(). `.querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList. [Read the DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) and burn old browsers.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan `for ... of` works as well.

Comment: @LoveshDongre Check the updated answer. It works.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in one go using `':nth-child(2)'` or `'*:nth-child(2)'`
will apply for both `th` in `thead` row, and `td` in `tbody` rows:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('table tr').forEach(tr => {
   tr.querySelector('*:nth-child(2)').style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>A1</td><td>A2</td><td>A3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>B1</td><td>B2</td><td>B3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```